# Aptana studio FTP connection missing

Tags: ftp, aptana, aptana3

Since the last update, after starting the Application the FTP-Server-Connections in "Project Explorer" are missing. Usually I can easily select the server and browse the files, but now after 1 second all the list entries are lost and it only shows "Local Filesystem" anymore..

(Before under Local Filesystem was my server listed: http://d.pr/i/zBc1 )
Yesterday I re-added it and I thought it would work, but today it's lost again...

EDIT: also re-installed Aptana Studio3. But still 1 second after starting the list entries get lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I created a completely new workspace now and it worked. Had to be an error with the Setting-files or something like that...